# http OAuth response error

Tags: java, android, http, oauth, hmacsha1

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        Log.d("HTTP","Exe");
        String sw=Sign(token);
        Log.d("HTTP","Exe");

        HttpPost httpPost;
        Log.d("HTTP","Exec");
        httpPost = new HttpPost(sw);
        Log.d("HTTP","Execute");

        HttpResponse response;
        try 
        {

            Log.d("HTTP","Executed");
//**THIS IS WHERE IT STOPS EXECUTION**

                response = httpclient.execute(httpPost); // the request executes
                Log.d("HTTP","Executed");
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 256);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  sb.append(line); 
                String result = sb.toString();
                is.close();
                Log.d("HTTP",result);
                String  responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(((HttpResponse) response).getEntity());
                retString=responseBody;
                Log.d("HTTP",result);

            } 

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //return null;

        return null;
    }
```

My LogCat:

```
06-25 23:45:59.105: D/HTTP(5993): wz27t6thob0fbxl
06-25 23:46:03.223: D/HTTP(5993): Exe
06-25 23:46:03.766: D/HTTP(5993): 1340648163
06-25 23:46:05.378: D/HTTP(5993): https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/dropbox/a.jpg?oauth_consumer_key=2f2y1dyuqhp58ek&oauth_token=wz27t6thob0fbxl&oauth_nonce=1340648163&oauth_timestamp=1340648163&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=bo%2F5zuowvX%2Fcjy5uPP5ZPjUiP64%3D%0A
06-25 23:46:05.402: D/HTTP(5993): Exe
06-25 23:46:05.402: D/HTTP(5993): Exec
06-25 23:46:06.132: D/HTTP(5993): Execute
06-25 23:46:09.363: D/HTTP(5993): Executed
06-25 23:46:38.742: D/dalvikvm(5993): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5331 objects / 305856 bytes in 400ms
06-25 23:46:51.413: D/HTTP(5993): Executed
06-25 23:46:51.952: D/HTTP(5993): {"error": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.dropbox.com%2F1%2Fshares%2Fdropbox%2Fa.jpg&oauth_consumer_key%3D2f2y1dyuqhp58ek%26oauth_nonce%3D1340648163%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1340648163%26oauth_token%3Dwz27t6thob0fbxl%26oauth_version%3D1.0"}
06-25 23:47:49.032: W/dalvikvm(5993): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.getContent(BasicHttpEntity.java:84)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:100)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:112)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:146)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at cloud.mobile.DropboxApi.doInBackground(DropboxApi.java:145)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at cloud.mobile.DropboxApi.doInBackground(DropboxApi.java:1)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-25 23:47:49.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5993):     ... 4 more
```

The signed key(sw) is https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/dropbox/a.jpg?oauth_consumer_key=2f2y1dyuqhp58ek&oauth_token=wz27t6thob0fbxl&oauth_nonce=1340648163&oauth_timestamp=1340648163&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=bo%2F5zuowvX%2Fcjy5uPP5ZPjUiP64%3D%0A

I do not have much experience with http..

since
            httpPost = new HttpPost(sw);
works fine,does that mean Base String Signature is correct?

or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not related to OAuth error. Based on following log statement, it seems you didn't set host in http post url.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
```

Comment: :Can you explain the problm now

Comment: You added token, that is good, but where is the url you are trying to access? How your code will know which computer/network it need to talk? There should be some url with network details. For example, if your code need to talk with google, your url will be google.com. Your code missing that part.

Comment: i thought ' https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/dropbox/a.jpg' part of signed key(sw)would be enough.
Should i specify it explicitly?